# joining tables with both results

Tags: sql

I have two tables, t1 and t2.  t1 holds contract numbers, while t2 holds contract events for those contracts.

I am trying to select all contracts from t1 and all records from t2 that match t1, but also trying to return all records from t1 where they don't match t2. 
My query seems to just bring back all records that match both tables.

I have tried:

- left join
- inner join and
- left outer join

and yet I still get the same result.

t1 holds 293 results, t2 holds 270 events.  Some of the t2 events have multiple events for 1 contractid, while some accounts have no events registered against them.

I want to bring back all `contractID`s and all events linked to that `contractID`, but I also want to return the contracts that have no event, having null in the `contractID` column.

My current query:

```
            SELECT  p.contractfk 
                    ,[GetEnddate](p.ContractFK) [Contract End Date] -- function
                    ,CASE 
                                WHEN c.StartDate IS NULL THEN 1
                                WHEN c.StartDate > ce.CreatedDate THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                                END [PreEngineer]
                    ,CASE 
                                WHEN c.StartDate < ce.CreatedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                END [PostEngineer]
            FROM [CRM].[pbx].[PBX] p
                    LEFT JOIN [ContractEnquiry] ce
                        ON ce.ContractFK = p.ContractFK 
                    LEFT JOIN [Contract] c
                        ON [c].[contractID] = [P].[contractfk]
```

Comment: Where is your query that doesn't work?

Comment: You'd best post your table definitions for T1 and T2 as well.  From your description, a `left outer join` should work fine.

Comment: Does CRM.pbx.PBX table have all the contract ID's?  You show it as foreign key in your select list, which makes it seem like you've got the wrong table as the base.

Comment: PBX holds all PBX contracts, contracts holds all contracts including PBX contracts and other types of contracts.

Comment: As an aside (for the future), `left join` = `left outer join` (a left, right, or full join is always an outer join, so, if you omit `outer`, it is implied).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a basic left outer join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 left outer join
     t2
     on t1.contractId = t2.ContractId;
```

If you then want to get *one* contract, be sure to choose from `t1` and not `t2`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 left outer join
     t2
     on t1.contractId = t2.ContractId
where t1.contractId = MYCONTRACTID;
```

If you choose from `t2`, you will turn the `left outer join` back into an `inner join`.

Comment: what is MYCONTRACTID?

Comment: It is your contract id... LOL. Just kidding. If you would like to have a filtering with contractId, you can replace MYCONTRACTID with original value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have your order of tables mixed around a bit, and you have to select ContractID if you want to return it. You can re-order the tables in your query:

```
        SELECT  DISTINCT c.contractID 
                ,[GetEnddate](p.ContractFK) [Contract End Date] -- function
                ,CASE 
                            WHEN c.StartDate IS NULL THEN 1
                            WHEN c.StartDate > ce.CreatedDate THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END [PreEngineer]
                ,CASE 
                            WHEN c.StartDate < ce.CreatedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END [PostEngineer]
        FROM [Contract] c
                LEFT JOIN [CRM].[pbx].[PBX] p
                    ON c.[contractID] = p.[contractfk]
                LEFT JOIN [ContractEnquiry] ce
                    ON ce.ContractFK = p.ContractFK
```

Comment: this just duplicates contract id's brings back 368 rows when only 270 evbents and 293 contracts

Comment: Your table structure is a bit of a mystery, so it's hard to answer definitively.